# How is a global variable set to private understood in swift?

Tags: swift, core-data, singleton

I'm working through a Core Data exercise from a book and it starts out creating a helper class which is a singleton.  I understand that global variables can be created outside of a class's scope and accessible throughout the project however where I'm confused is than an example from the book creates a global variable and sets it to private.  I assumed that by setting a variable to private, it is only accessible to that specific class.  This private global variable is created outside of the helper class so I assume its accessible by all classes in the project therefore the private keyword isn't necessary.  Can anyone help by confirming if my assumptions are correct or incorrect as I'd really like to understand.

Here is the code from the book's example:

```
import Foundation

import CoreData


//this is a global variable accessible from any module or class
private let _sharedCDHelper = CDHelper()

class CDHelper: NSObject {

    // MARK: - SHARED INSTANCE
    class var shared: CDHelper {
        return _sharedCDHelper
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A private global variable in Swift is a global that is only accessible from the file in which it is declared.

The book you are using isn't following current best-practice as far as creating singletons in Swift (perhaps it is a little out-dated?).

There is no need for the private global variable.  You can just say:

```
class CDHelper: NSObject {
// MARK: - SHARED INSTANCE
    static let shared = CDHelper()
}
```